# How to describe a function type without `any` type?

Tags: typescript, function

If use `any` type, it like this:

```
type MyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any

// It's okay!
const fn: MyFunction = (a: string, b: number) => {
  // ...
}
```

But, If I don't use `any` type, it like this:

```
type MyFunction = (...args: unknown[]) => unknown

// It report an error!
// Type '(a: string, b: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'MyFunction'.
// Types of parameters 'a' and 'args' are incompatible.ts(2322)
const fn: MyFunction = (a: string, b: number) => {
  // ...
}
```

What should I do without `any` type?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigAoA6UgQwCcBzAZwC4oUBrZLAd2QG0BdASnwB8jZC3bIAsACgpAehlQAksADkNKBQhgsFYFDK4IFCtoCEs+QBVw0ZYTIMawChmRUANFABGDZIgC2nob8eEIAblgYACbKUBhqrLpkNDQYVMhkngA20MBYUKCQUMpwSGiYOMrE5lBWkGpYAGZQYJRkfhDAhmrKZDH6kUWUtH0asWhYfi2YWRDEwDSEAEwAzIuLvFKoOI5QDcgMJSjo2LgEdg5OLu5ePv6BFMFCAN5SUFByUKRVkgC+UkA)

------------ update ---------------

Sorry to everyone, I did not describe this question clearly.

Actually, I practice to realize Typescript Utility Type `Parameters`, and I write this:

```
type MyParameters<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown> = T extends (...args: infer A) => unknown ? A : never;
```

And I see the official `Parameters` in `lib.es5.d.ts` is:

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

Then test it:

```
type MyParameters<T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown> = T extends (...args: infer A) => unknown ? A : never;

type TestFunction = (a: string) => string

// OK!, Got [a: string]
type Params1 = Parameters<TestFunction>

// Error!
type MyParams = MyParameters<TestFunction>
```

Comment: Well what do you actually want the `MyFunction` type to represent?

Comment: It's unclear what the goal is. Why do you have vararg function which can apparently accept any type at all? That is not useful at all as an interface, as all implementations can be different, thus you cannot ensure type safety or proper operation. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Function types are *contravariant* in their parameter types, so to generalize a function parameter you need to move toward `never` and not toward `unknown`.  That is, `(...args: never) => unknown` is very general.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvE5Bm).  But you basically can't call such a function safely anymore, since you have no idea what parameters it takes.  You can also use the `Function` interface, but this is untyped and allows all kinds of weird calls and isn't really better than `any`.  So, what is your use case?  Once you have such a `MyFunction` value, what will you do with it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hm, what's the purpose of removing the "any" in the parameters if they're never used directly but only to feed into the "infer"